# sql query details for a certain date

Tags: sql, date

I have the following database:

```
create table Hotel  (
   HNo char(4),
   Name varchar(20)   not null,
   Address varchar(50),
   Constraint PK_Hotel Primary Key (HNo))
)


create table Room  (
   RNo char(4),
   HNo char(4),
   Type char(6) not null,
   Price decimal (7,2),
   Constraint PK_Room Primary Key (HNo, RNo),
   Constraint FK_Room Foreign Key (HNo)
   references Hotel (HNo)
)


create table Guest  (
   GNo char(4),
   Name varchar(20) not null,
   Address varchar(50),
   Constraint PK_Guest Primary Key (GNo)

)


create table Booking   (
   HNo char(4),
   GNo char(4),
   DateFrom date,
   DateTo date,
   RNo char(4),
   Constraint PK_Booking Primary Key (HNo, GNo, DateFrom),
   Constraint FK_Booking Foreign Key (GNo)
   references Guest (GNo),
   Constraint FK_Booking_room Foreign Key (HNo, RNo)
   references Room (HNo, RNo),
   Constraint FK_Booking_hotel Foreign Key (HNo)
   references Hotel (HNo)
)
```

What I am struggling with is using the `dateto=> <=datefrom` and getting it to work.

For the 26th march 1997, I need to list the details of all rooms in all hotels, including the name of any guests who were staying in the room. I'm not too bad with joining the tables etc, but am not sure how to do it as a whole on the specified date? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
  h.Name,
  h.Address,
  r.RNo,
  r.HNo,
  r.Type,
  r.Price,
  G.Name,
  G.Address,
  ...
FROM Hotel         AS h
INNER JOIN Room    AS r  ON h.HNo = r.HNo
INNER JOIN Guest   AS g  ON r.RNo = g.RNo
INNER JOIN Booking AS b  ON b.GNo = g.GNo
                        AND b.HNo = h.HNo
WHERE b.DateFrom <= @DateFrom
  AND b.DateTo   => @DateTo;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  SELECT b.datefrom, b.dateto, h.name AS hotelname
         , b.rno
         , r.type
         , g.name AS guestname
    FROM booking b
    JOIN hotel h ON b.hno = h.hno
    JOIN guest g ON g.gno = b.gno
    JOIN room r ON b.rno = r.rno
   WHERE @yourDate BETWEEN b.datefrom AND b.dateto
```

**EDIT :**

Replace the `@yourDate` in the last line with a suitable expression supported by your DBMS.

E.g., in Oracle, there is a function `TO_DATE` which converts a given string to date, like `TO_DATE('26-MAR-1997') BETWEEN b.datefrom AND b.dateto`. In SQL Server there is `CAST` function.